# Why is it not waiting for an awaited Promise.all to resolve?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, axios

I previously had working code that inefficiently called awaits on every element of an iterable. I'm in the process of refactoring to use Promise.All. **However, my code is not waiting for the Promise.All to resolve before executive further code.**

Specficially, the `purgeRequestPromises` line executes before the initial `Promise.All` resolves. I'm not sure why that is? `retrieveSurrogateKey` is an async function, so its return line will be wrapped in a resolved promise.

```js
try {
    //retrieve surrogate key associated with each URL/file updated in push to S3
    const surrogateKeyPromises = urlArray.map(url => this.retrieveSurrogateKey(url));
    const surrogateKeyArray = await Promise.all(surrogateKeyPromises).catch(console.log);

    //purge each surrogate key
     const purgeRequestPromises = surrogateKeyArray.map(surrogateKey => this.requestPurgeOfSurrogateKey(surrogateKey));
     await Promise.all(purgeRequestPromises);

     // GET request the URLs to warm cache for our users
     const warmCachePromises = urlArray.map(url => this.warmCache(url));
     await Promise.all(warmCachePromises)
} catch (error) {
    logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in purge cache: ${error}`);
    throw error
} 

async retrieveSurrogateKey(url) {
    try {
        axios({
            method: 'HEAD',
            url: url,
            headers: headers,
        }).then(response => {
            console.log("this is the response status: ", response.status)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log("this is the surrogate key!! ", response.headers['surrogate-key'])
                return response.headers['surrogate-key'];
            }

        });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in retrieveSurrogateKey: ${error}`);
        throw error
    }
}
```

I know that the purgeRequestPromises executes early, because I get errors complaining that I've set my Surrogate-Key header as `undefined` in my HEAD request:

```js
async requestPurgeOfSurrogateKey(surrogateKey) {
    headers['Surrogate-Key'] = surrogateKey

    try {
        axios({
                method: `POST`,
                url: `https://api.fastly.com/service/${fastlyServiceId}/purge/${surrogateKey}`,
                path: `/service/${fastlyServiceId}/purge${surrogateKey}`,
                headers: headers,
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("the status code for purging!! ", response.status)
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return true
                }
            });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in requestPurgeOfSurrogateKey: ${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can debug what's going on.

Comment: `retrieveSurrogateKey()` isn't returning the axios call

Comment: explanatory example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dhcmr5fe/

Comment: "*retrieveSurrogateKey is an async function, so its return line will be wrapped in a resolved promise.*" - but nothing in your code indicates that this promise should wait for the `axios` call, and notice that the `retrieveSurrogateKey` function does *not* have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retrieveSurrogateKey` is synchronously returning `undefined`: the value in the `try` block is a promise and no errors are thrown synchronously, so the `catch` clause is never executed and execution falls out the bottom, returning `undefined` from the function body.

You could try something like:

```
function retrieveSurrogateKey(url) {  // returns a promise
    return axios({
//  ^^^^^^
        method: 'HEAD',
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("this is the response status: ", response.status)
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("this is the surrogate key!! ", response.headers['surrogate-key'])
            return response.headers['surrogate-key'];
        }

    }).catch(error => {
       logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in retrieveSurrogateKey: ${error}`);
       throw error;
    });
}
```

Note that it is superfluous to declare a function returning a promise as `async` if it doesn't use `await`. There is also a secondary problem in this line:

```
const surrogateKeyArray = await Promise.all(surrogateKeyPromises).catch(console.log);
```

The `catch` clause will will fulfill the promise chain unless the error is rethrown. You could (perhaps) leave off the `.catch` clause or recode it as

```
.catch( err=> { console.log(err); throw err} );
```

Comment: _"the value in the try block is a promise and no errors are thrown synchronously, so the catch clause is never executed and execution falls out the bottom, returning undefined from the function call."_ It returns `Promise.resolve(undefined)`, not `undefined`. Also, instead of removing `async` and making everything a promise chain, you could have left it as is and inserted `return await` before the call to `axios(...)` in order for the promise rejection to propagate to the `catch` block that was in the original code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts changed `call` to `body` for accuracy. The promise chain was already presented in the question so I converted the `catch` block into a `catch` clause for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove `async` from `retrieveSurrogateKey()` in order for it to work. In fact it's more readable if you don't. As was already explained, the problem is that the promise returned by `retrieveSurrogateKey()` does not follow the completion of the promise returned by the call to `axios()`. You need to `await` it:

```js
async retrieveSurrogateKey(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'HEAD',
      url,
      headers,
    });

    console.log('this is the response status: ', response.status);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const surrogateKey = response.headers['surrogate-key'];
      console.log('this is the surrogate key!! ', surrogateKey);
      return surrogateKey;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in retrieveSurrogateKey: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This preserves the same logic you currently have, but you'll notice that when `response.status !== 200`, you end up with a resolved promise of `undefined`, rather than a rejected promise. You might want to use [`validateStatus`](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) to assert the exact status of 200. By default axios resolves any response with a status >= 200 and < 300:

```js
async retrieveSurrogateKey(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'HEAD',
      url,
      headers,
      validateStatus(status) {
        return status === 200;
      } 
    });
    
    const surrogateKey = response.headers['surrogate-key'];
    console.log('this is the surrogate key!! ', surrogateKey);
    return surrogateKey;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.save(`${'(prod)'.padEnd(15)}error in retrieveSurrogateKey: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This way, you're always guaranteed a surrogate key, or a rejected promise.